# read certificate from smartcard

Tags: java, applet, smartcard

I am trying to read certificates from   smart card ,

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
                Provider pkcs11Provider =new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11("c:\\dev\\pkcs11.cfg");
                char [] pin = {'1', '2', '3', '4'};
                KeyStore smartCardKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11",pkcs11Provider);
                smartCardKeyStore.load(null, null);
                Enumeration aliasesEnum = smartCardKeyStore.aliases();
                while (aliasesEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                   String alias = (String)aliasesEnum.nextElement();
                   System.out.println("Alias: " + alias);
                   X509Certificate cert =
                   (X509Certificate) smartCardKeyStore.getCertificate(alias);
                   System.out.println("Certificate: " + cert);
                   PrivateKey privateKey =
                      (PrivateKey) smartCardKeyStore.getKey(alias, null);
                   System.out.println("Private key: " + privateKey);
                }

    }

}
```

I got this from http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3587361/Java-Applet-for-Signing-with-a-Smart-Card.htm
I will be executing this code in applet, the problem with this is every user has to point me their  local pkcs11...dll , 
does using java samrtcard api can we  avoid loading this dll? (did not find any examples  of loading certificates using java smartcard api)
using SunPKCS11  is there any way applet jar can include the dll so that client browser need not  provide me

Comment: Smartcard has CSP layer above PKCS#11 which makes all Certificates (not private key) in it available in Certificate Store as soon as you insert it.  You may use Browser Extensions for Modern browsers to sign by writing couple of lines of code to use methods provided by Browser Extension. My Co. provides one such free [Browser Extension](https://signer.digital/SignerDigitalBrowserExtensions) for modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There is if you use JWS/JNLP to define the applet, instead of the `<APPLET>` tag.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: using java smartcard api   does it make any simpler reading certificate from smart card?

Comment: any example of code using java smartcard api to read certificates ?

Comment: @SubinJacob Your comment makes no sense. The answer is to use JWS.

Comment: @user884424 Your question already contains the code. Your problem was with the DLL, and that's what I answered.